# Grouping data in UWP DataGrid

Tags: windows-community-toolkit

I am trying to display `Information` objects grouped by `Context` property with in the UWP DataGrid using the code below. The first method creates a `ObservableCollection<GroupInfoCollection<Information>>();` which is set to the `CollectionViewSource.Source` as shown in second part. And the XAML used is shown at the very end.

I can see the group headings as `Group` in UI, but without any subitems. I am not sure what I am missing. Also the group headers are not showing the `Context` property name.

```
var query = from item in exception.Information
  group item by item.Context into g
  select new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = g };

var information = new ObservableCollection<GroupInfoCollection<Information>>();

foreach (var group in query)
{
  var info = new GroupInfoCollection<Information>
  {
    Key = group.GroupName
  };
  foreach (var item in group.Items)
  {
    info.Items.Add(item);
  }
  information.Add(info);
}
return information;
```

```
CollectionViewSource groupedItems = new CollectionViewSource
{
  IsSourceGrouped = true, 
  Source = information // returned from above method
  };
InformationGrid.ItemsSource = groupedItems.View;
```

```xml
                <controls1:DataGrid x:Name="InformationGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                    <controls1:DataGrid.Columns>
                        <controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="48">
                            <controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="jama:Information">
                                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="{x:Bind local:JamaOptionPage.GetGlyph(Level)}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="220">
                            <controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="jama:Information">
                                    <HyperlinkButton Content="{x:Bind Name}" NavigateUri="{x:Bind Link}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </controls1:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <controls1:DataGridTextColumn Header="Error" Binding="{Binding Message}"/>
                    </controls1:DataGrid.Columns>
                </controls1:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made two mistakes. My implementation of `GroupInfoCollection` was bit flawed. Instead of

```cs
public class GroupInfoCollection<T>
{
  public string Key { get; set; }
  public List<T> Items { get; set; } = new List<T>();
}
```

it should be

```cs
public class GroupInfoCollection<T> 
{
  public object Key { get; set; }
  public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
}
```

Also, the header was coming empty, for which one require something like

```cs
InformationGrid.LoadingRowGroup += InformationGridOnLoadingRowGroup;


private void InformationGridOnLoadingRowGroup(object sender, DataGridRowGroupHeaderEventArgs e)
{
  var group = e.RowGroupHeader.CollectionViewGroup;
  var item = group.GroupItems[0] as Information;
  e.RowGroupHeader.PropertyValue = item.Context;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to get `GroupInfoCollection.Key` in `InformationGridOnLoadingRowGroup`?

Answer (score 0):

This implementation of `GroupInfoCollection` works for me

```
public class GroupInfoCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public object Key { get; set; }
    public new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
         return (IEnumerator<T>)base.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```